# Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved error in RTL

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a basic login form made using *Formik*, just trying to write an RTL and jest code to fill out the details, submit the form, and navigate to the *Home page*. Therefore, wrote the following:

```js
 it('Fill the form and login', async () => {
    render(<Login />)

    await userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId('emailInput'), 'neeraj@gmail.com')
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId('passwordInput'), 'neeraj')
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('submitBtn'))

    expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/')
  })
```

The above test is getting passed but getting the classic *act* error.

```
When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
```

So, referred to this [blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/fix-the-not-wrapped-in-act-warning) and used **waitForElementToBeRemoved** function as suggested but now the test is getting failed with a timeout error.

*Updated test case with waitForElementToBeRemoved*

```js
it('Fill the form and login', async () => {
    render(<Login />)

    await userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId('emailInput'), 'neeraj@gmail.com')
    await userEvent.type(screen.getByTestId('passwordInput'), 'neeraj')
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('submitBtn'))

    expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/')
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByTestId('emailInput'))
  })
```

*Error:*

```
 Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved.

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <html>
      <head />
      <body>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div
              data-testid="loginCard"
            >
              <form
                data-testid="loginForm"
              >
                <div>
                  <label
                    for="email-input"
                  >
                    Email
                  </label>
                  <input
                    data-testid="emailInput"
                    id="email-input"
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    value="neeraj@gmail.com"
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label
                    for="pass-input"
                  >
                    Password
                  </label>
                  <input
                    data-testid="passwordInput"
                    id="pass-input"
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    value="neeraj"
                  />
                </div>
                <button
                  data-testid="submitBtn"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>

      19 |
      20 |     expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/')
    > 21 |     await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByTestId('emailInput'))
         |           ^
      22 |   })
      23 | })
      24 |

      at waitForElementToBeRemoved (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for-element-to-be-removed.js:22:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/login.test.js:21:11)
```

Tried to wrap those three *userEvent* s in *act* function but getting the same timeout error, couldn't figure out where I am going wrong.

[*Code Sandbox link*](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-tu-n2m0j?file=/README.md)

Comment: waitForElementToBeRemoved expects a callback function. You are passing screen.getByTestId('emailInput') which is not a callback, but a function call that immediately executes. Try changing it to callback like this await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => screen.getByTestId('emailInput'))

Comment: Tried it. Still getting the timeout error. Added the code sandbox link in the edit, the file is _login.test.js_ inside the _tests_ folder in case you want to peek into it

Comment: Ok, I have looked into it. waitForElementToBeRemoved is timing out because the element is never removed. I don't see any code removing it.  Are you expecting router.push to remove it? That onSubmit part of code is not executing at all likely because of your validator.

Comment: And let us suppose that part executes, It is possible that it still timeouts because you are already at URL path "/" and not at "/login" because this is is a unit test. Try console.log(window.location.pathname) at the start of the test and you are already at "/" (you don't have full fledged navigation API in unit tests).

Comment: And when you happen to make that part of onSubmit execute (by removing or satisfying the validator), you start getting problems with the router. This is exactly what unit tests are for. They are not only to show us the errors but to indicate design problems and right now I think it is a design problem.

Comment: I will recommend going for rewriting this login component. Making it simpler. Try dependency injection on some dependencies so that you can mock them in the test, especially the ones that can cause trouble in the unit test.

Comment: Hey, @EresDev thanks for the input. Although, the problem lied in the submit handler of the form which is using `setTImeout` as pointed out _Subrato Patnaik_ in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to pass the test case with no act warnings.

Since you are calling an setTimeout which is an asynchronous function when the user clicks on the `submitBtn` button, therefore you have to wait for the promise to resolve.

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import React from 'react'

import Login from './../pages/login'

describe('Login Page', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    render(<Login />)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('loginCard')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  
  it('Fill the form and login', async () => {
    render(<Login />)

    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/email/i), 'neeraj@gmail.com')
    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/password/i), 'neeraj')
    userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('submitBtn'))

    await waitFor(() => expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/'))
  })
})
```

You could also do it using async act on the click event which will going to be wait for the promise to resolve and state updates to complete.

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import React from 'react'

import Login from './../pages/login'

describe('Login Page', () => {
  it('renders without crashing', () => {
    render(<Login />)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('loginCard')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  
  it('Fill the form and login', async () => {
    render(<Login />)

    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/email/i), 'neeraj@gmail.com')
    userEvent.type(screen.getByLabelText(/password/i), 'neeraj')
    await act(async () => userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('submitBtn')))

    expect(window.location.pathname).toBe('/')
  })
})
```